# https://example.com/.well-known/exampletxt can not access .well-known folder

Tags: magento2

I want to access a encrypted file by accessing
https://example.com/.well-known/example.txt

It is not working.

I can access https://example.com/pub/.well-known/example.txt

In the backend, I checked below files.

/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/magento-https-vhost.conf

/home/bitnami/stack/magento/app/etc/env.php

can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

This folder is hidden,
-First, enable the "Show hidden files" in Windows settings. then try to search.